# Oracle SQL query optimization - getting counts based on a varchar field

Tags: sql, oracle

Optimizing a query

I have a query getting data from one table and getting two counts from two other tables based 
on a varchar field TYPE. I need to get count from TABLE2 where TYPE=TABLE1.TYPE and 
count from TABLE3 where TYPE=TABLE1.TYPE

At this point I cannot create any indexes on those fields so I decided to use functions which brought my original query execution time
down to 5 seconds which is still too much. Any suggestions on how to further optimize my query?

```
 SELECT     a.ID, 
    a.FIELD1, 
    a.FIELD2, 
    a.TYPE, 
    GET_COUNT_1(a.TYPE) as COUNT1,
    GET_COUNT_2(a.TYPE) as COUNT2,
FROM TABLE1 a
```

my original query was:

```
SELECT  a.ID, 
    a.FIELD1, 
    a.FIELD2, 
    a.TYPE, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE2 b WHERE b.TYPE=a.TYPE) as COUNT1,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE3 c WHERE c.TYPE=a.TYPE) as COUNT2
FROM TABLE1 a
```

Comment: Did you try using JOIN? Can you post your original SQL and time?

Comment: Using a function on every row selected is unlikely to be the fastest method because of the context switch between SQL and PL/SQL. You could try correlated subqueries - e.g. (select count(*) from table2 where table2.type=a.type) as count1 - but joining will usually provide best performance. Have you got up to date stats on tables? What is query plan using join?

Comment: @rs. I added my original query although I know it was very inefficient

Comment: @Lord Peter, that is exactly what i did before and it took like 15 seconds. With functions it went down to 5 seconds

Comment: Both subqueries seem to be identical and should produce the same count. Is this really what you want ?

Comment: From the earlier description, the second subquery should be against `TABLE3`, right? Are those timings consistent - if you run that original query multiple times does it always take 15 seconds, or just the first time? (Your function version could just be benefiting from data cached when you ran the original query...)

Comment: Alex Poole, it still take long even if I re-run it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not have index on the `table2(TYPE)` it is deadly to use subquery as you will repeatedly (for each row of `TABLE1`) perform a *FULL TABLE SCAN*.

Aparently the Oracle subquery cashing, that could save you, did not kick in.

The function approach will be not much better, except you implement some fucntion result caching on your own.

But there is a simple solution to *precalculate the counts* in a subquery and join the result to `TABLE1`.

Note that you **calculates the `count` only once for each type** and **not for each row of the TABLE1**

```
with cnt as 
(select type, count(*) cnt
from table2 group by type),
cnt2 as 
    (select type, count(*) cnt
    from table3 group by type)
select a.ID, 
    a.FIELD1, 
    a.FIELD2, 
    a.TYPE,
    b.cnt cnt1
    c.cnt cnt2
from  TABLE1 a 
left outer join cnt b
on a.type = b.type
left outer join cnt2 c
on a.type = c.type
```

You will end with one `FTS` for each table, aggregation and outer join, which is the minimum you need to do.

Comment: how would I add one more table to this?

Comment: @CodingDuchess added in the example

Answer (score -1):

For your query, you want an index on `table2(type)`.

The two subqueries are exactly the same, except for the table alias.  If you really have two different tables, or if you are using different columns, then you'll want the appropriate index for that expression.

Comment: as I did mention, unfortunately, I cannot create indexes at this time